# java.lang.IllegalAccessError and Exception in Application start method in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

This is my Main.java class:

https://pastebin.com/A0WQLJAj

This is my Controller.java class:

https://pastebin.com/vPvrEFVM

This is my sample.fxml file:

https://pastebin.com/y8Qtkr80

And this is the error I get:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x205e01a7) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x205e01a7
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at javabrowser.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application javabrowser.Main
```

I would like to know what it means and how I can fix it, I've tried other solutions with VM arguments and changing the path file.

Comment: Try adding `javafx.fxml` to the `--add-modules` command.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain in more detail what you mean by that.

Comment: The error is basically saying the `javafx.fxml` module is being used from the classpath when it needs to be used from the modulepath. As your own code is not modular (I assume), you probably have the `--add-modules` argument configured somewhere (i.e. `--add-modules javafx.controls`). I'm suggesting you try including the `javafx.fxml` module in that argument. The information in [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) may prove helpful; it shows how to configure your project for various IDEs/build tools both for modular and non-modular applications.

Comment: Ok after adding this to the arguments: `--module-path /Desktop/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` I recieve this error: `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found
`

Comment: Hmm. Not sure about that one. Assuming you have a valid JavaFX SDK, the `javafx.base` module should definitely be under the `lib` directory and be pulled in by both `javafx.controls` and `javafx.fxml`. For whatever IDE or build tool your using, try following the instructions in [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) exactly—maybe you'll come across something that was accidentally incorrectly configured.